# AWS CodeBuild unable to download gradle wrapper

Tags: amazon-web-services, gradle, gradlew, aws-codebuild

I am using gradle to build a Java application on AWS. However when I am trying to build the code, CodeBuild throws the following exception when trying to download Gradle

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target 
   at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192) 
   at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1949) 
   at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302) 
   at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296) 
   at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1514) 
   at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216) 
   at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1026) 
   at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:961) 
   at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062) 
   at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375) 
   at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403) 
   at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387) 
   at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559) 
   at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185) 
   at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1546) 
   at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1474) 
   at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254) 
   at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:66) 
   at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:51) 
   at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:62) 
   at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48) 
   at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:69) 
   at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48) 
   at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:107) 
   at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61) 
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target 
   at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:387) 
   at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292) 
   at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260) 
   at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324) 
   at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229) 
   at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124) 
   at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1496) 
   ... 20 more 
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target 
   at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141) 
   at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126) 
   at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280) 
   at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:382) 
   ... 26 more 

[Container] 2019/01/23 21:43:56 Command did not exit successfully sh gradlew clean test exit status 1
```

Anybody facing the same problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am also having this issue, AZ is Sydney Australia.

I changed from the Amazon Linux Docker Image to Ubuntu and it started working.